# What is the benefit of the 'paperclip' gem styles option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

This is probably a very newb question but here it goes:

The paperclip gem has an option called :styles which saves multiple versions of the image in different sizes. My question is, since I can use css to resize an image to my desired size, what's the benefit of saving multiple versions of the same image?

Cheers!

Uri

Comment: Yes, it is a newb question, but that's how you learn. As long as you're not asking us to write your code, you'll do well here. This is how I got my start programming. SO's a good place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS only scales an image.

So, for example, if you allow a 1 MB image to be uploaded, but you're scaling it to `200X200` px for a thumb, the browser will still download the 1MB image.

The `:style` option lets you save a few different sizes so you can keep your server load down.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS only scales images and synchronize image, so the image is not a good resoluction, another advantage is the memory for your server if you  use an image more then five times on page then it will load image every time so, better is use styles according to required image with pixel.

```
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => {:big => "200>x200", :header_img => "101x101#"},
    :path => ":root/public/system/albums/:id/:style.:extension",
    :url => "/system/albums/:id/:style.:extension",
    :default_url => "/images/rails.png"
```